# Sorting array of hashes with its keys

Tags: ruby

i have an array of hashes

```
arr = [
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife", :gifted => "true" },
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife" },
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife" },
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife", :gifted => "true" }
]
```

I am trying to sort the array hashes on the basis of :gifted=> "true". like this

```
sorted = [
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife", :gifted => "true" },
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife", :gifted => "true" }
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife" },
  { :tap=> "bucket", :mobile=> "charger", :apple=> "knife" }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.sort_by{|h| h[:gifted] == "true" ? 0 : 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your implementation you could also group these items

```
arr.group_by{|h| h[:gifted]}
#=>=> {"true"=>[{:tap=>"bucket", :mobile=>"charger", :apple=>"knife", :gifted=>"true"}, {:tap=>"bucket", :mobile=>"charger", :apple=>"knife", :gifted=>"true"}], nil=>[{:tap=>"bucket", :mobile=>"charger", :apple=>"knife"}, {:tap=>"bucket", :mobile=>"charger", :apple=>"knife"}]}
```

so to get true objects

```
arr.group_by{|h| h[:gifted]}["true"]
#=>[{:tap=>"bucket", :mobile=>"charger", :apple=>"knife", :gifted=>"true"}, {:tap=>"bucket", :mobile=>"charger", :apple=>"knife", :gifted=>"true"}]
```